# Specifying an exit function for an abstract function

Tags: python, interface, atexit

I need a way to call a function from an abstract method, i.e.

```
class A(object):

      @abc.abstractmethod
      def method1(self):
           raise Exception("Unimplemented method")

      def method2(self):
           print "method1 finished"

class B(A):
     def method1(self):
         print "executing method1 from class B"
```

I need a way to automatically call `method2` of class `A`, after the `method1` has been executed (It should be done on the class `A` side - independently from inherited classes).

Is there a nice way of doing this?

Comment: As you've inherited from `A`, you can simply call `self.method2()`.

Comment: Sounds like you want to document in your API that anyone implementing `method1` must call the overridden version at the end, or directly call `self.method2` at the end. Or require that implementors of `method1` use a decorator.

Comment: I want to do everything on the class A side

Comment: @MartijnPieters - exactly, but in a way that it is transperent from the inhereted classes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a metaclass, which wraps `method1` at the time the class is created:

```
from functools import wraps

class MetaA(type):
    def __new__(meta, name, bases, attr):
        method1 = attr['method1']
        if not getattr(method, '__isabstractmethod__'):
            @wraps(method1)
            def wrapper(self, *args, **kw):
                res = method1(self, *args, **kw)
                self.method2()
                return res
            attr['method1'] = wrapper
        return super(MetaA, meta).__new__(meta, name, bases, attr)

class A(object):
     __metaclass__ = MetaA

     @abc.abstractmethod
     def method1(self):
         raise Exception("Unimplemented method")

     def method2(self):
         print "method1 finished"
```

This applies what is basically a decorator to a specific method whenever a (sub)class is created.

Another approach, somewhat hackish, is to intercept the method access, but would work. You'd implement a `__getattribute__` hook on `A` that adds a wrapper:

```
from functools import wraps

class A(object):
     @abc.abstractmethod
     def method1(self):
         raise Exception("Unimplemented method")

     def method2(self):
         print "method1 finished"

     def __getattribute__(self, name):
         obj = super(A, self).__getattribute__(name)
         if name == 'method1':
             @wraps(obj)
             def wrapper(*args, **kw):
                 res = obj()
                 self.method2()
                 return res
             return wrapper
         return obj
```

Either approach results in:

```
>>> B().method1()
executing method1 from class B
method1 finished
```

By using the [`@functools.wraps()` decorator](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html#functools.wraps) the wrapper maintains several important attributes from the wrapped method, like its name and docstring.

Comment: hackish indeed, but clever.

Comment: @schmi: you can make `MetaA` inherit from `abc.ABCMeta`.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a job for the [Template method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern) pattern, for example:

```
class A(object):
  def method1(self):
      # do something before
      try:
          self.method1_impl()
      finally:
          # do something after, for example:
          self.method2()

  @abc.abstractmethod
  def method1_impl(self):
      pass

  def method2(self):
      print "method1 finished"


class B(A):
    def method1_impl(self):
        print "executing method1 from class B"
```

While I'm not a proponent of this style (it tends to become hard to comprehend as the code grows and becomes more complex), this is occasionally used and has right to exist.

Answer (score 1):

When this kind of situation happens, it can usually be solved by overriding "deeper" functionality.

Instead of having `class B` override `method1`, make it override `method1_subfunction`, and call both `method1_subfunction` and `method2` from `method1`

```
class A(object):

    def method1(self):
        self.method1_subfunction()
        self.method2()

    @abc.abstractmethod
    def method1_subfunction(self):
        raise Exception("Unimplemented method")

    def method2(self):
        print "method1 finished"

class B(A):
    def method1_subfunction(self):
        print "executing method1 from class B"
```